# MySQLdb. Преобразование данных в строку

Tags: python, mysqlconnector

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(db=parsed.path.strip('/'),
                             host=parsed.hostname,
                             user=parsed.username,
                             passwd=parsed.username)
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.set_character_set('utf8')
sql_doc = """SELECT file_name FROM orders o  WHERE  o.period < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 84 MONTH)"""
cursor.execute('SET NAMES `utf8`')
cursor.execute(sql_doc)

data_sql_doc = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data_sql_doc:
    print(str(row))
```

Получаю вот такой вывод:

```
('/usr/local/billing/reports/reports-04141/197001/14151382.xml',)
('/usr/local/billing/reports/reports-04141/197001/14151397.xml',)
('/usr/local/billing/reports/reports-04141/197001/14151383.xml',)
```

как преобразовать данные что бы с путями к файлам можно было работать? К примеру os.revome.

При попытке просто обрезать лишние символы, `print(str(row[2:3]))`, получается фиаско, точнее пустые скобки::

```
   ()
   ()
   ()
```

Comment: row является кортежем (tuple). Интересующая вас строка хранится в нем под индексом 0. Используйте `row[0]` для ее получения.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как преобразовать данные что бы с путями к файлам можно было работать?

Ну так получайте сразу отдельно путь, отдельно имя.

```
SELECT file_name fullname, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_name, '/', -1) filename, 
       LEFT(file_name, LENGTH(file_name)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_name, '/', -1))-1) filepath
FROM orders o  
WHERE o.period < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 84 MONTH)
```

Comment: Проблема то не в том что путь и имя в одной строке. а в том что эта стока имеет непонятный мне тип данных и я не знаю как с ней работать.

Comment: @АндрейКотов ну с этим Вы разобрались. А вот поделить на части, если записей не вагон, лучше на SQL-сервере (и, если не надо, то не тянуть полное имя, брать только запчасти) - сервер имхо всё это выполнит эффективнее.

Answer (score 0):

Может использовать method join()

```
for row in data_sql_doc:
    myString = ''.join(row)
    print(myString)
```